# how to combine sync and async function in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronization

I have problems with the synchronous and asynchronous functions on NodeJS, here is my problem,

I have 4 functions, a global variable (users), and a rendering function to have the html page.

the scraper1 and scraper2 function can be performed asynchronously, they scrape a website and fill in the global user variable, and the data_selector1 cannot be done unless scraper1 has done the same for data_selector2 with the scraper2 functions.

1-I need that scraper1 and scraper2 work asynchronously and fill the available users, and only render the HTML page if the 2 scrapers have finished their work.

2-I need an animation to be displayed in the browser during the drilling process, how can I do this

Here is what I tried ..

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require('fs');
var router = express.Router();

 /*  globale variable to populate */

    var users = { 
                'name':null,
                'age':null,
               

            };

//function of scraping link1

function scarper1(callback){
    console.log("-------------scraper---------");
    var url = 'link1';

request(
  {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://api.myscarperwebservice.com/?url=' + url,
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
    },
  },
  function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw error;
    // call the data-selector1 after scraper are finish rendering
    data_selector1(body);
    
    


  }
);


}

//function of scraping link2
function scarper2(callback){
  console.log("-------------scraper2---------");
  var url = 'link2';

request(
  {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://api.myscarperwebservice.com/?url=' + url,
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
    },
  },
   function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw error;
    // call the data-selector2 after scraper are finish rendering
    data_selector2(body);
    
    


  }
);


}


function data_selector1(body)
{
console.log("-------------data-selector---------");
  const $ = cheerio.load(body);
  $("div[class='.user']").each(function(i,elem){
    

            users['name'] =$(elem).find('span[class=".name]').text();
          
            users['age'] =$(elem).find('span[class=".age]').text();
            
            
  });

}

function data_selector2(body)
{
console.log("-------------data-selector2---------");
  const $ = cheerio.load(body);
  $("ul[class='.user']").each(function(i,elem){
    

        users['name'] =$(elem).find('li[class=".name]').text();
          
        users['age'] =$(elem).find('li[class=".age]').text();
      
        
  });

}




/* GET home page. */

router.post('/recherche', function(req, res, next) {
   // i dont know how to make it here to say that scraper1 and scraper2 can be executed async and to render page after that the two scraper are finished 
   // and while scraper are working to display animation in the client
    scarper1(function(results){
        console.log(results);res.render('rechercher', { title: 'Express' });
        
    });
    
    
  
});
```

Comment: LOL scarper means to run away. You mean scraper.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `promise.all()` to do that but before you can use it, you need to promisify your functions:

```
function scarper1(callback) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("-------------scraper---------");
        var url = 'link1';

        request(
            {
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://api.myscarperwebservice.com/?url=' + url,
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                },
            },
            function (error, response, body) {
                if (error) reject(error);
                // call the data-selector1 after scraper are finish rendering
                data_selector1(body);
                resolve('Done successfully');
            }
        );
    });
}

function scarper2(callback) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("-------------scraper2---------");
        var url = 'link2';
        request(
            {
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://api.myscarperwebservice.com/?url=' + url,
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                },
            },
            function (error, response, body) {
                if (error) reject(error);
                // call the data-selector2 after scraper are finish rendering
                data_selector2(body);
                resolve('Done successfully');
            }
        );
    });
}

let scarper1 = scarper1(function(results){
    console.log(results);res.render('rechercher', { title: 'Express' });

});
let scarper2 = scarper2(function(results){
    console.log(results);res.render('rechercher', { title: 'Express' });

});

Promise.all([scarper1, scarper2]).then(function(values) {
    console.log(values);
});
```

For more about [promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) check this docs.

An even better approach is using [`async.eachLimit()`](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#eachLimit) to loop through requests (asynchronously) but first you need to install [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) package then merge both **scraper** functions:

```
const async = require("async");
let urls = [
    'link1',
    'link2'
]
async.eachLimit(urls, 2, (url) => {
    console.log("-------------scraper---------");
    request(
        {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://api.myscarperwebservice.com/?url=' + url,
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
            },
        },
        function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) reject(error);
            // call the data-selector1 after scraper are finish rendering
            if(url == 'link1')
                data_selector1(body);
            else
                data_selector2(body);

            resolve('Done successfully');
        }
    );
}, (err) => {
    console.log("Finished all urls")
});
```